# Bitwise AND of two Chars prints wrong result

Tags: c#, types, char

When I run this code -

```
string binNumber="11111000001";
for(int ind=0; ind<binNumber.Length; ind++){
   Console.WriteLine(binNumber[ind]&'1');
}
```

it prints sequence of 49 and 48 instead of 1 and 0.

I could not understand why is it happening? If I use the XOR operator it prints 1s & 0s. I have seen this behavior for & and | operator.
The code can be accessed in the IdeOne here - https://ideone.com/fqZFUY.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/544990/Understand-how-bitwise-operators-work-Csharp-and-V

Comment: You shouldn't use `string` to hold binary number. Any *integer type* by nature is better to hold binary. Use e.g. [`UInt16`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint16(v=vs.110).aspx) to hold value. Only [convert it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1838963/1997232) to `string` when you want to show it. This way your *binary* arithmetic will work as intended (assuming you will do it with *integer* values and not `string`/`char`).

Comment: See [BitArray](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20650932/1997232) as well.

Comment: @Sinatr, thanks a ton. I was not aware of this class in the Collections namespace. Plus, is probably the right way to handle the situations I am encountering today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'0'` has a code of 48 in decimal, or 110000 in binary.

`'1'` has a code of 49 in decimal, or 110001 in binary.

110000 & 110001 == 110000 == 48 decimal

110001 & 110001 == 110001 == 49 decimal

So when you do `Console.WriteLine(binNumber[ind]&'1');` you get 48 or 49 depending on whether `binNumber[ind]` is '0' or '1'.

Remember that if you do `someChar & someOtherChar` the compiler does a bitwise AND of the numeric values of those chars.

Comment: Will this be advisable - binNumber[ind]&1 ?

Comment: @SivaSenthil It doesn't appear to make much sense - what are you actually trying to achieve? Do you really want to convert a string representation of a binary number to an integral version?

Comment: @Mathew not exactly, I do not intend to do any conversion. I want to display the result of bitwise binary operation. That's all.

Comment: @SivaSenthil Then `binNumber[ind]&1` would be correct, assuming you want to AND the character code with the value `1`.

Answer (score 0):

The type of an `&` operation between two `char` is `int`. You can see it if you try:

```
var res = '0' & '0';
```

and you look at the type of `res`. (technically this is called "binary numeric promotion", and what happens in this case is that both `char` are converted to `int`, then the `&` is done between two `int`, and clearly the result is an `int`. If you are interested it is explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa691330.aspx))

So being the result an `int`, `Console.WriteLine` formats it as an `int`.

Try

```
Console.WriteLine((char)(binNumber[ind]&'1'));
```