# How to store a bit in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
void MyBitMaker(int inputNumber)
{
    Console.WriteLine(inputNumber << 1);

    //TODO
    //Bit bitHolder = inputNumber << 1;
    //InitMico(ref bitHolder);
}
```

There is not a type for storing bits in `C#`. Is there any way to store bits in a variable.

I am programming a micro controller using `C#`, It uses the bits that are coming from a web service, fetches them and sends them to the controller to open, close, sleep and such things using an interface to change the input data to appropriate bits. My problem is that the micro has just 16 bytes memory in ram and I can not store more than two bytes, the micro should store the history of previous actions (this is extra, maybe, jargon). I have low space and need this small unit. I searched a lot and did not find anything. currently I am using bit operators using a class that I myself have implemented but it's not efficient at all because of using bit operations. I was wondering if someone has faced something that can help me.

Comment: You can't address a bit by itself. That's imposed by the hardware. The smallest addressable unit of information is a byte.

Comment: try using boolean maybe?

Comment: @active92 I need a bit to be referenced

Comment: @media oh yea. sorry. boolean is a byte. my bad.

Comment: You could pass a reference to an entire `int` and the mask selecting the particular bit. How you should do this depends on what exactly you intend to do with with that referenced bit though.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean by "I need to reference to that" or "I need a bit to be referenced". Please try to clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: There is a class called BitArray which internally uses boolean values to show if a bit is set or not but uses less space than an BooleanArray but is heavier on performance.

Comment: @media This link can helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650651/best-way-to-store-retrieve-bits-c-sharp

Comment: @JonSkeet I am using ref and I need some variable to reference to that. It  is vital in other methods in my program

Comment: @harold I know that, but I wanted to know if there are any other solutions.

Comment: Nope, that's still *incredibly* unclear. Sure, you can create your own `Bit` type if you want... is that what you're looking for? (Why are you using `ref` anyway? Are you sure you really need to?) This question is *really* vague...

Comment: I have low space for ram and need to have ref variable, the size of stack in the controller is so low. If I use int I will have problem because of low space

Comment: 3 redundant bytes is going to be a problem? That sounds pretty unlikely, to be honest. But it sounds like you have a *lot* of requirements which aren't mentioned at all in your question.

Comment: Indeed, than .NET would be the wrong choice @JonSkeet

Comment: @JonSkeet I edited

Comment: I'm struggling to see how the program itself is going to fit into 16 bytes...

Comment: @PatrickHofman the micro just works with .NET

Comment: @JonSkeet its not needed to hold the program. just the bits are needed to have history of previous actions, and they are needed to be referenced

Comment: Well I don't know about anyone else, but *I'm* still extremely confused by the requirements. I think you'll be very lucky if you find anyone able to help you with the question in its current state. But fundamentally you're not going to be able to declare any type which has less than a single byte requirement for storage. You could use a single byte to store 8 bits, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just want to store bits

Trivial solution: bool array.

If it really needed to store the bits in a compacted form, you can use the [`BitArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) type, which uses an int array internally. You can index it similarly to a normal array:

```
var myBits = new BitArray(20); // initialize for 20 bits (1 int will be stored internally)
myBits[5] = true; // similar to this: myInt |= 1 << 5;
```

Comment: I do not have more than tow bytes. bool stores two one entire byte

Comment: If you have up to 8 flags, use a byte and do the masking yourself. Same for up to 16 flags and and ushort. But practically it doesn't matter and if compacting matters you can always use the `BitArray` (or `BitVector32`) types because even if you use a byte, it will be aligned to 32 or 64 bits in memory.

Answer (score 2):

The smallest addressable unit is a `byte`, so use that, or a `bool` which is still 8 bits, but only has two possible values to be set.

You can't reference a bit, so that would be useless anyway. If you need to address a specific position in a `byte`, you can pass along the position. Still, you can only change the bit's value by setting the entire byte.

Comment: AFAIK bool is not always stored in a byte because of memory alignment. The SQL Server bit type is stored in bool too.